# Start app on device boot, but not run service

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, intentfilter

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` that is using the `BOOT_COMPLETED` `intent-filter` in the `AndroidManifest`, which then runs my `Service` when the device boots.  Is it possible to have my `Service` start, but not actually run the code in the `Service`?  I have an `AlarmManager` that run the `Service` at a regular interval, but, ideally, I'd like that code to not run when the device starts.

```
<receiver android:name="com.app.AlarmReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, call startActivity:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.MainActivity");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear, what I meant to say was have my `Service` and `AlarmManager` start on boot, but not actually run the `Service` code.  I don't want my app to actually display to the user when it starts.

Comment: So if your Service runs, but not your Activity, nothing will display to the user. BTW, what do you mean by "have my Service and AlarmManager start on boot, but not actually run the Service code"?

Comment: Basically, my app runs my `Service` at a specific interval using the `AlarmManager`.  So I want the `AlarmManager` to start when the device boots, but I don't want the `Service` to run it's code when the device boots.  I want the code in the `Service` to run at the next interval after the device boots.  I guess what I need is a way to detect, in the `Service`, whether the device just booted.

Comment: Oh. Then have the BroadcastReceiver kick off the AlarmManager on boot, and the AlarmManager kick off the Service.